# Shell script to rename files based on parent folder name with a twist

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I started out with an Automator droplet but it was a bit too clunky on larger numbers of files. I think a shell script is probably going to work better, but I'm not sure how to proceed...

What I want is to rename a large number of files replacing part of the file name with the parent folder name while retaining the serialisation of the files and their file extension.

Here is the folder/file structure and what I would like it transformed to

```
/Path/to/Folder/XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G
|____XYZ_123_028_V001.000000.abc
|____XYZ_123_028_V001.000001.abc
|____XYZ_123_028_V001.000002.abc
...
|____XYZ_123_028_V001.000099.abc
|____XYZ_123_028_V001.000100.abc
```

to

```
/Path/to/Folder/XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G
|____XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000000.abc
|____XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000001.abc
|____XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000002.abc
...
|____XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000099.abc
|____XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000100.abc
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're not here to write things for you, but we'll help you fix your script if you post it.

Comment: I hope next time s/he'll try first before asking.

Comment: I totally didn't expect anyone to write anything for me. I genuinely was just after some pointers on how to approach this. I had started with sed, but I now believe that is better for file content rather than file name manipulation. The answer is very much appreciated. I will attempt to post something more useful next time.

Comment: Solution to your question is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759422/rename-files-to-their-parent-folder)

Comment: Solution to your question is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759422/rename-files-to-their-parent-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$ pwd
/jenkins/do_no_delete_AKS_data/XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$ for i in {1..10}; do touch XYZ_123_028_V001.00000$i.abc ; done
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.0000010.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000001.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000002.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000003.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000004.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000005.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000006.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000007.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000008.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001.000009.abc
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$ dir=$(basename `pwd`); grab=${dir##*_V001}; for f in `ls `; do echo -e "\nFilename = $f"; echo -e "Moving $f -to- ${f%%.*}$grab.${f#*.}\n"; mv $f "${f%%.*}$grab.${f#*.}"; done
Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.0000010.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.0000010.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.0000010.abc

Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000001.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000001.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000001.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000002.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000002.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000002.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000003.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000003.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000003.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000004.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000004.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000004.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000005.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000005.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000005.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000006.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000006.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000006.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000007.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000007.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000007.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000008.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000008.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000008.abc


Filename = XYZ_123_028_V001.000009.abc
Moving XYZ_123_028_V001.000009.abc -to- XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000009.abc

[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.0000010.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000001.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000002.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000003.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000004.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000005.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000006.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000007.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000008.abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 0 Jun 12 18:55 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G.000009.abc
[jenkins@sb12 XYZ_123_028_V001_F01A_9G]$
```